# WordPress.org Support Forum API

Tags: api, support

WordPress.org provides several API end-points for data about themes and plugins.

For example for plugins there is the plugin_api:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_api/

And the themes API:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/themes_api/

But, what about a Support API?

The best option I have so far is to parse data from each forums RSS feed - for example:

https://wordpress.org/support/rss/plugin/export-user-data

But this returns the last 30 replies accross all topics for the specified plugin.

We would like to get

- All the forum topics from the last 3 months
- Each entry in those topics, with info such as author name, date, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: What data do you want, exactly?

Comment: Thanks Otto - I updated the ticket with a little extra info

Comment: @QStudio This is off-topic here. I am sure Otto will gladly help you if you drop him an email.

Comment: @MarkKaplun - please explain why it's off topic.

Comment: well,  it has nothing to do with wordpress core.

Comment: It "might" - I'm asking if there are additional API calls such as plugin_api() which is a core function - to get info about plugins hosted on wordpress.org

Answer (score 2):

That´s no big deal if you got the RSS feed, have a look at it.

There is a `pubDate` which you can use to check for the age of the topic. [`strtotime()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.strtotime.php) or anything alike will help you to check if that´s older than 30 days.

And you also got a `link`-element. This leads you to the topic, which has its own RSS feed, too.

**Example:**

```
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cron-job-to-ftp#post-7943160
=> https://wordpress.org/support/rss/topic/cron-job-to-ftp
```

This is probably not as comfortable as a full API but nevertheless a good way to go.

Comment: But the original feed returns the 30 latest entries, which might be from topics new or old - I need to get the latest x topics as the starting point before I parse over the data to get extra info.

Comment: I will probably end up scraping the topics from the plugin URL and then pulling entries from the RSS feeds of each topic - not ideal, but perhaps the best solution for now.

Comment: I don´t see any other way right now, sorry.

Comment: `https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/export-user-data/feed/` will return the last 30 topics new to old, but if you need the last *active* topics (new to old), you can use `https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/export-user-data/active/feed/`. LIkewise for the unresolved topics: `https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/export-user-data/unresolved/feed/`. But yes, an API (especially if it allows to post answers too) would be awesome.

Comment: @Ewout - surfe thing youre right. I think that we need a API that supports the fetching of the data of the forums - i work on it. - again thanks for the help you provide